# SignalR Hub: Visual Studio 2013 debugger does not stop on a break point inside public override Task OnConnected() { }

Tags: visual-studio-2013, signalr, visual-studio-debugging, signalr-hub

I use SignalR 2.1.1, I do have one client callback function which is wired *before* starting the hub (http://goo.gl/vwquxR).
Still, Visual Studio 2013 debugger does not stop on a break point inside public override Task OnConnected() { }.
I put some logging into OnConnected(), so I know it's fired. I also know that SignalR JavaScript client is working - it connects and client callback function is successfully hit by calling it from a server hub.

Please help.

Comment: The VS debugger takes some time to attach to the IIS process. Can that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know. Probably not... My JavaScript client and SignalR hub reside in separate applications: a web form and Web Api service, correspondingly. But I can launch everything on local IIS with Visual Studio (web form is a startup project) and when yet another Web Api service calls a Web Api service which is hosting SignalR hub - a break point inside controller action works. It seems to be something special about Hub class / OnConnected handler which doesn't allow to stop. BTW, debugger doesn't stop inside Owin Startup either, although Startup code works.

Comment: I don't currently have server any server methods defined, only one client callback method. Does it matter?

Comment: @Anders - you might be right. WebApi app to WebApi app http call doesn't stop in debugger in controller action of second app either. Although it was stopping just yesterday, when there was a bit less code. But if I launch a second copy of Visual Studio with WebApi app and have it launched, then it stops when called by other app.